# How to bypass Process builder while mass update through quick action on list view?

Tags: process-builder, quickaction

I have a process builder on custom fields of case object. I want a mass update quick action on List view. Using this mass update quick action I would like to update three fields of selected cases on list view. But while mass updating the cases process builder is restricting the update and not allowing the change. How to overcome this? any workaround. I don't want to change the process builder. Thanks

Comment: Depends whether your PB fires if record CHANGES or always?

Comment: PB fires whenever record changes.

Comment: So, you might be updating any field of PB condition which may change and fire the PB? If that's right then you dont have any option ... create a checkbox field "Stop Automation" and add in PB to fire only if this field is false. And while updating the record, update the checkbox as well

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard feature for bypassing the automation. [See idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V0000015KFrQAM)